# How do I force a resolution of 1024x768?

Tags: xorg, resolution

back in ubuntu 9, maximum resolution supported was 960x600, by editing xorg.conf i was able to get 1024x768 resolution. i recently installed ubuntu 11.10.. now again maximum resolution i can get in display panel is 960x600 .. i tried editing xorg but there was no xorg and when i tried to create one access was denied.

I'm new to linux commands so, step by step help will be appreciated.

I added `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` containing:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync       30.0-62.0
    VertRefresh     50.0-70.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
    Device        "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth    24
        Modes     "1024x768" "800x600"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I've had a very similar problem and I got it working reliably by [following these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/100907/5786). Give it a try!

Comment: for future reference if you only want to >quickly< set the resolution: - first run xrandr and find the settings - then  `xrandr --output OUTPUT -s "WxH" -r "F" --auto`

Answer (score 8):

1. Enter the command below in your terminal:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```
2. Copy and paste the following options into that file:

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier    "Configured Video Device"
   EndSection

   Section "Monitor"
       Identifier    "Configured Monitor"
       HorizSync       30.0-62.0
       VertRefresh     50.0-70.0
   EndSection

   Section "Screen"
       Identifier    "Default Screen"
       Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
       Device        "Configured Video Device"
       DefaultDepth    24
       SubSection "Display"
           Depth    24
           Modes     "1024x768" "800x600"
       EndSubSection
   EndSection
   ```
3. Save your edits, and restart (log out and back in or reboot).

Enjoy.

Comment: With regard to the HorizSync and VertRefresh lines, you should verify the values here against the frequency range of your monitor by checking its documentation.

Comment: Yeah, this does not work at all on 18.04

Answer (score 4):

Here is my solution using xrandr to force a resoultion of 1280x1024 at 75hz... Place the following in ~/.xprofile

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_75.00"  138.75  1280 1368 1504 1728  1024 1027 1034 1072 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 "1280x1024_75.00"
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode "1280x1024_75.00"
```

Note: VGA1 is the display device you want to adjust... also you can create any new modeline you might want/need by using the cvt command. I found the reference URI: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

Comment: Use cvt to get what to put into xrandr --newmode https://askubuntu.com/a/377944/1200475

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the same method you used before, but if you need to create xorg.conf do so as follows.  From the command line ("Terminal"):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Paste your configuration in there and save it.  Now the file should exist and you should be able to edit it like you did before.

If you need more help after you get that far, edit your question and we can continue. :)