# Computer starts, then asks for login, and then crashes

Tags: xorg, login, display, crash

I recently replaced my REALLY old windows OS with Ubuntu, and it looks like it works at first glance. When I attempt to log in, however, it accepts my username and password, then goes into what I believe is the Ubuntu equivilant of a blue screen.

[image: Photo of broken display]

How can I solve this?

Comment: It appears to be misconfigured X (graphics system) or incorrect drivers. Can you boot the system into single user mode? (At boot screen, select the recovery option). If the system drops you into a shell (command line) we can trouble shoot from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are overdriving your monitor.  In other words, the video card is using a refresh frequency that is higher than what your monitor can support.  Try switching to a text-mode console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>.

If that works, you may be able to [manually reconfigure Xorg.conf](https://askubuntu.com/q/74808/165556) to [reduce the display resolution](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution).